# Is it possible to draw a graph that has an Euler Cycle but not a Hamilton Path?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is it possible to draw a graph that has an Euler Cycle but not a Hamilton Path?

It seems every Euler cycle I draw has a Hamilton Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take three squares, call them $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$. Let vertices be the corners of the squares, and let edges be the sides.  Now identify one vertex of $S_1$ and $S_2$ and identify the antipode of the already identified vertex of $S_2$ with a vertex of $S_3$.

Comment: If the vertices are ABCDEFG: the edges A-B, A-D, B-C, C-D, C-E, C-G, E-F, F-G. Then a Hamiltonian Path is B-A-D-C-E-F-G

Comment: Yeah, I goofed.  I edited it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take two triangles, join them at one of the vertices.

Comment: Is it possible to post a link of a google image of some kind? I see a Hamilton Path when I draw.

Comment: the vertices are ABCDE, the edges A-B A-C B-C C-D D-E C-E

Comment: @Oiclid it's not a Hamilton path because the triangles' common vertex must be visited twice.

Comment: I guess, I am not sure why the adjacency list is not sufficient.

Comment: A-B-C-D-E is a Hamilton Path

Comment: Ah, yes, not cycle but a path. I was looking for a graph with no cycle.

Comment: Well, there's a difference between exhibiting a graph with a Hamiltonian path, and exhibiting one that has a Hamiltoniam path but no Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: If it has a Hamiltonian Cycle then it has a Hamiltonian Path, but if it has a Hamiltonian Path, it may or may not have a Hamiltonian Cycle.

Comment: Plus, I might add, the problem has been entirly changed.  See y answer below.

Comment: If two triangles don't work, take THREE triangles, join them at a common vertex.  The Eulerian cycle is there, but no hamiltonian path.